# How to inset automatic data in Cells using app script in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: 1]

`

```
var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;
    
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D3").getValue()); 
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F4").getValue()); 
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B7").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E7").getValue());
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F7").getValue()); 
   
   if(shUserForm.getRange("C7").isBlank()==false){  
    var blankRow2=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;

datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D3").getValue()); 
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F4").getValue()); 
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E7").getValue());
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow2,4).setValue(stock.getRange("T3").getValue()); 
    }
    if(shUserForm.getRange("D7").isBlank()==false){  
    var blankRow3=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;

datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D3").getValue()); 
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F4").getValue()); 
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D7").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E7").getValue());
   datasheet.getRange(blankRow3,4).setValue(stock.getRange("U3").getValue()); 

    }
```

`

i alreday insert first row data from sheet to another sheet using this code , i need to insert more rows withowt repeating last code.

Comment: What does inset mean?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.getRangeList()` and `Array` methods, like this:

```js
  let firstCellA1 = 'B7';
  ['D7', 'C7', 'B7',].some(rangeA1 => {
    if (shUserForm.getRange(rangeA1).getDisplayValue()) {
      firstCellA1 = rangeA1;
      return true;
    }
  });
  const data = shUserForm
    .getRangeList([firstCellA1, 'E7', 'F7', 'F3', 'B3', 'D3', 'F4',])
    .getRanges()
    .map(range => range.getValue());
  datasheet.appendRow([new Date()].concat(data));
```